# Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm having issues with scrolling to the top of the web page when using Python and Selenium.

When the page loads for some reason you are taken to the bottom of the page (this is due to be fixed). However, when I'm trying to scroll to the top it does not work.

I tried the following:

```
self.driver.execute_script("scroll(0, -250);")
```

And

```
self.driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 0);")
```

I have also tried locating the element then scrolling to it:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element)
```

The above scrollIntoView() code works when scrolling down to the element. However, it does not work scrolling up.

I have tried this running Chrome Driver and PhantomJs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried putting `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` inside of your `execute_script`?

Comment: @mangoHero1 I've tried `self.driver.window.scroll("window.scroll(0, 0);")` and the script displayed the following error:
 _self.driver.window.scroll("window.scroll(0, 0);")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'window'_

Comment: @mangoHero1 sorry I saw the typo corrected it and did the following: `self.driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0, 0);")` still didnt scroll up.

Comment: @jlaur yeah sorry this was done late at night and I typed the code above. What i actually tried, which didnt work, was the following: `self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can consider to locate the element in the `HTML DOM` first, then we can `scroll` the element into the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Answer (score 36):

You can simply use `CTRL` + `HOME` keys. It will scroll to the top of the page.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
```

Comment: probably need to `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` first?

Comment: @ErichBSchulz, yes, that's correct. `Keys` needs to be imported.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the browser is minimized

Comment: If you get the following warning: `DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead`

change the code to:
`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)`

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to scroll up or down

1)scroll by pixel

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,0)","")
```

2)scroll down until the element is not found

```
element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpath of element")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element)
```

3)scroll till the end of the page

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

4. using Action Chains

   elementpos=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpath of element")
   actions=ActionChains(driver)
   actions.move_to_element(elementpos).perform()

Answer (score 2):

You can use document.body.scrollTop: it will scroll to the top of the page no matter the height of it.
Like this:

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollTop);")`

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("__")

#to scroll try use the following command
driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,250);")
```

It will work !!

Comment: Please add more details to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('div[role=dialog] ul').parentNode.scrollTop=1e100")
```

Answer (score 1):

from selenium import webdriver

```
t=10
while t:

#if you want to scroll to the end of the page,use this

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(3)


#if you want to scroll down upto some level use this, here i used "1000" you may vary 
#it according to your use

driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,+1000);")
    sleep(3)


#if you want to scroll some level up, use this,again i used here "-500" you may vary 
#according to your use 

driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,-500);")
sleep(3)
t=t-1       # it`s a part of the loop
```

This will surely help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.body.scrollTop: a javascript variable which contains the value by what the page had been scrolled down before that.
like this :
`driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,-document.body.scrollTop)")`