# Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to play [QWOP](http://www.foddy.net/Athletics.html?webgl=true) using Selenium on Chrome but I keep getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
{"method":"id","selector":"window1"
(Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913
(36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c), platform=Linux 4.10.0-42-generic x86_64)
```

while using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_window_size(640, 480)
browser.get('http://www.foddy.net/Athletics.html?webgl=true')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

canvas = browser.find_element_by_id("window1")

canvas.click()

while (True):
    action = ActionChains(browser)
    action.move_to_element(canvas).perform()
    canvas.click()
    canvas.send_keys("q")
```

The same code works perfectly on Firefox, but because I want to use chrome's capability to run an webgl game in headless mode I can't really switch to Firefox.

Any workarounds to get this working?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### NoSuchElementException

*selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException* popularly known as `NoSuchElementException` is defined as :

```
exception selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException(msg=None, screen=None, stacktrace=None)
```

`NoSuchElementException` is basically thrown in 2 cases as follows :

- When using :

  ```
  webdriver.find_element_by_*("expression")
  //example : my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_expression")
  ```
- When using :

  ```
  element.find_element_by_*("expression")
  //example : my_element = element.find_element_by_*("expression")
  ```

As per the API Docs just like any other `selenium.common.exceptions`, `NoSuchElementException` should contain the following parameters :

- msg, screen, stacktrace

  ```
      raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='create-portal-popup']/div[4]/div[1]/button[3]"}
    (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64)
  ```

---

### Reason

The reason for *NoSuchElementException* can be either of the following :

- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't identifies any element in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted is unable to identify the element as it is not within the browser's [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted identifies the element but is invisible due to presence of the attribute **style="display: none;"**.
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't **uniquely** identifies the desired element in the *HTML DOM* and currently finds some other *hidden* / *invisible* element.
- The *WebElement* you are trying to locate is within an `<iframe>` tag.
- The *WebDriver* instance is looking out for the *WebElement* even before the element is present/visibile within the *HTML DOM*.

---

### Solution

The solution to address *NoSuchElementException* can be either of the following :

- Adopt a [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which uniquely identifies the desired *WebElement*. You can take help of the *Developer Tools* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) and use *Element Inspector*.

  Here you will find a detailed discussion on [how to inspect element in selenium3.6 as firebug is not an option any more for FF 56?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-in-selenium3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-for-f/46702281#46702281)
- Use [**`execute_script()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method to scroll the element in to view as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
  ```

  Here you will find a detailed discussion on [Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium/45581830#45581830)
- Incase element is having the attribute **style="display: none;"**, remove the attribute  through `executeScript()` method as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", elem)
  elem.send_keys("text_to_send")
  ```
- To check if the element is within an `<iframe>` traverse up the *HTML* to locate the respective `<iframe>` tag and `switchTo()` the desired *iframe* through either of the following methods :

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_name")
  driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_id")
  driver.switch_to.frame(1) // 1 represents frame index
  ```

  Here you can find a detailed discussion on [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879).
- If the element is not *present*/*visible* in the *HTML DOM* immediately, induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) set to proper method as follows :

  - To wait for [**presence_of_element_located**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) :

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath']")))
    ```
  - To wait for [**visibility_of_element_located**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) :

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")
    ```
  - To wait for [**element_to_be_clickable**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) :

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "element_link_text")))
    ```

---

### This Usecase

You are seeing `NoSuchElementException` because the *id* locator doesn't identifies the **canvas** uniquely. To identify the canvas and `click()` on it you have to wait for the **canvas** to be `clickable` and to achieve that you can use the following code block :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//canvas[@id='window1']"))).click()
```

---

### Reference

You can find [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [java](/questions/tagged/java) client based relevant discussion in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)

Comment: I copied the wrong error, I just edited the question with the correct error and your advice implemented. I still get the same error.