# No Such Element Found Error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

No matter what search type I use, I always get "no such element found" error. Why does this happen?

```
public void CorrectPIN() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")).sendKeys("abhisingh1313@mailinator.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
     do {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } while (driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed());
}
```

..................
I am getting unable to locate element on `driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed())` no matter what search mechanism I use. I have tried even xpath. 
basically I want the webdriver to wait until an element is present on screen and it does but even then I don't know why it gives error unable to locate the element error.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: NoSuchElementExceptio:unable to locate element (method:id,selector:pin)

Comment: Please put that information into your question. Do you have a line number?

Comment: yes it is :  } while (driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed());

Comment: basically i want the webdriver to wait untill an element is present on the screen ..

Comment: it does wait .. but i dont know why it thoriws this error. no matter what find element method i use. i have used xpath etc

Comment: I repeat myself: "Please put that information into your question."

Comment: This means that the element with the *id* {pin} is not displayed.

Comment: but it is displayed . i have tried with other elements on the page with different findelement element methods but same result

Comment: is the element with the pin id inside an iframe?  you'll need to switch to that iframe the call findElement

Comment: no its not . basically . if i write findelement.by id(pin).send keys- it works .
the thing i am not getting here is . if the element is not displayed . then it should come out of loop rather than failing the method :(

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your Question correct, after all your steps when checking the condition within `while()` loop i.e.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed();
```

You are seeing a **`NoSuchElementException`**.

The Java Docs clearly mentions that [**`NoSuchElementException`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) is thrown by either **`WebDriver.findElement(By by)`** or **`WebElement.findElement(By by)`** which matches your case.

### Reasons

There can be a lot many reasons to see [**`NoSuchElementException`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html). A couple of them are as follows :

- The [**`Locator Strategy`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements) which you have used i.e. `id` may not be identifying the exact element.
- The element may not be within the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- When your script searches for the element, by that time the element may not have rendered in the `HTML DOM`

### Solution

The solutions for the above mentioned reasons would be :

- Adopt a [**`Locator Strategy`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements) which which will uniquely identify the intended element, preferably a [**`Css Selector`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByCssSelector.html). You can find a detailed discussion in [**`Official locator strategies for the webdriver`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)
- Use `JavascriptExecutor` to bring the element  within the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) with the following line of code. You can find a detailed discussion in [**`Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium/45581830#45581830)

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
  ```
- Use [**`WebDriverWait`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) along with proper [**`ExpectedCondition`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for the `WebElement` to be interactive.

---

### Update

You are seeing `NoSuchElementException` at the following line :

```
while (driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed());
```

From your code block it is inconclusive why you want to check **`driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed()`** in a `while loop`. Once you do **`driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();`** you are redirected to a new page with a new **`HTML DOM`**. So on the new page if you want `driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed()` to be successful you have to induce `WebDriverWait` for the `WebElement` to be **displayed** as per my Answer's Solution#3.

Comment: Thanks man for such an explaination. it was really helpful for me . i just want to add one thing here: i feel the webdriver is able to locate the element beucase it the execution is paused .. whta i am doing after that is . i am manually enter the PIN . and clicking continue and then the element (pin field) is gone and my execution resumes and starts checking other stuffs.. only problem i have is .. even the execution is successfully resumed . it gives me NSE for that specific step. i hop ei wa sable to expain myself . it would be helpful if you can help  me here.

Comment: I have updated my Answer. Factually, even though `the webdriver is able to locate the element` still **driver.findElement(By.id("pin")).isDisplayed()** can be unsuccessfull. See [ExpectedCondition](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) documentation. If my **`Answer`** have catered to your **`Question`** please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my **`Answer`** just below the **`VoteDown`** arrow so the tick mark turns **`Green`**.