# Element identified through find_element_by_xpath returns selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have problem with click button. This button can click if enemy is on play and can't click if enemy go out
start
I tried with this:

```
try:
    element= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='butwb']")
    if element.is_displayed():       
        print ("Element found")
    else:
        print ("Element not found")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No element found")
```

Result:

```
Element not found
```

If I add `element.click()` :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: You have located an element that is not visible. You haven't necessarily done anything wrong. If you tried a wait and it never became visible, then it probably never will. It's possible that you are identifying the wrong element. Selenium was designed to not allow interactions with invisible elements (simulates a user). I would suggest that you test your locator in the browser dev console using `$x()`.

Comment: @JeffC  Can I connact with you private message?

Comment: You can contact me here.

Comment: I can't do much with the code. The part I need is a link to the site and a description of what button you are trying to click.

Comment: https://www.kurnik.pl/pilka/#118 @JeffC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Kuncioso and getting into a game, we found that there were two buttons that matched his locator and the first was hidden. The problem was solved using the code below to click the second button, the one he wanted.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='butwb']")[1].click()
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

...implies that the element with which you were trying to interact was **not visible**.

The below line of code to identify the element was *successful*  as the element was present within the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) :

```
element= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='butwb']")
```

At this point it is worth to mention that, **presence** of element implies that element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not garuntees that the element is  **visible(i.e. displayed)** or **interactable (i.e. clickable)**.

> **Visibility** means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

Hence **`is_displayed()`** method returns **false** and `else{}` block is executed which prints :

```
Element not found
```

Further when you invoke **`click()`** the following exception is raised :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

### Probable Reasons

- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted is unable to identify the element as it is not within the browser's [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't **uniquely** identifies the desired element in the *HTML DOM* and currently finds some other **hidden** / **invisible** element.
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted identifies the element but is invisible due to presence of the attribute **style="display: none;"**.
- The *WebElement* may be present within a *Modal Dialog Box* and may not be visible/interactable immediately.

### Solutions

- Use [**`execute_script()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method to scroll the element in to view as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem);
  ```

  Here you will find a detailed discussion on [Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium/45581830#45581830)
- Incase the *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't uniquely identifies the desired element in the HTML DOM and currently locates some other *hidden* / *invisible* element as the first match the you have to change the *Locator Strategy*.
- Incase element is having the attribute **style="display: none;"**, remove the attribute  through `executeScript()` method as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", elem)
  elem.send_keys("text_to_send");
  ```
- If the element is not *present*/*visible*/*interactable* within the *HTML DOM* immediately, induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) set to proper method as follows :

  - To wait for [**presence_of_element_located**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) :

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath']")))
    ```
  - To wait for [**visibility_of_element_located**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) :

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")
    ```
  - To wait for [**element_to_be_clickable**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) :

    ```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "element_link_text")))
    ```

Comment: When "To wait for visibility_of_element_located :"      raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Kuncioso Did you try to _scrollIntoView()_ the element or check if the _attribute style="display: none;"_ or the element is a _hidden_  element?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium can you help to check this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72799696/selenium-checkbox-cannot-find-web-driver-expected-condition-failed-waiting-fo

Comment: @everalian You seem to have deleted the question.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium it is there pls check again.