# Always getting "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible" exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have tried maximum possible ways but always getting :

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

exception for specific web element (with in popup window) during execution of selenium script.

Element Xpath value is:
Element selector value is: #edited_name

Copied value of element is:

```
<input required="required" type="text" id="edited_name" name="edited_name" value="AT Main Category1" placeholder="" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Just to clear one thing.
===============================================
element xpath value is:         //*[@id="edited_name"]

element selector value is:     #edited_name

element value is:       <input required="required" type="text" id="edited_name" name="edited_name" value="AT Main Category1" placeholder="" class="form-control">

outer html is: <input required="required" type="text" id="edited_name" name="edited_name" value="AT Main Category1" placeholder="" class="form-control">

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_?

Comment: outer html is: <input required="required" type="text" id="edited_name" name="edited_name" value="AT Main Category1" placeholder="" class="form-control">

Answer (score 0):

- Try adding a wait - Explicit wait or Implicit wait to wait for the element to become visible. May be add a 10 seconds wait.
- Also, when using Xpath, don't use #, use `by.cssSelector("input#edited_name");`

Comment: Dear demouser123- Thanks for your quick response. as i shared i tried maximum possible ways but in vain. I already tried the wait statements which you suggested also not worked. I also tried by.cssSelector("input#edited_name") (which you suggested) but this is also not working and i am still getting same error
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: Is the element in a frame?

Comment: it's Modal popup window

Answer (score 0):

As the desired element is a `<input>` element you can induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

- `cssSelector` :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("//input.form-control#edited_name"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @id='edited_name']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Dear DebanjanB,
Thanks for your support but still getting below message
Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@class='form-control' and @id='edited_name'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: @Ali Check the _Probable Reasons_ and _Solutions_ in the discussion [Element identified through find_element_by_xpath returns selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182683/element-identified-through-find-element-by-xpath-returns-selenium-common-excepti/50183293#50183293)

Comment: Can you please take some time to know the difference between explicit wait and implicit wait? Explicit wait is set in local language binding but implicit wait is set in driver, so please don't suggest people to use explicit wait all the time.

Comment: Guys, can anyone propose any solution for my query?

Answer (score 0):

If your unvisible element is in a pop-up window, you need to switch the driver to the pop-up window.

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
driver.findElement(...
```

Comment: Dear pburgr,
Now I am getting below after adding the statement which you suggested:

org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open