# Selenium Checkbox cannot find - web driver Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser, chrome-web-driver

I am trying to use selenium for headless browser to trigger some input but one of the checkbox in the page is not able to identify. I tried with waiting 100 seconds, and without waiting, but still having the same error that element cannot find.
Below is the code. I tried with ID and xPath, both having the same error. Also with `visibilityOfElementLocated` and `elementToBeClickable` but same error.

When I try the xpath in the chrome inspect element, it finds only one element. So I think xpath is correct.

```
val wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@name = 'element_ID']")))
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@name = 'element_ID']")))

val elem: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id = 'element_ID']"))
elem.click()
```

Error

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element 
to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@name = 'element_ID'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.4', java.version: '1.8.0_321'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552518 (183d19265345f5..., userDataDir: /var/folders/06/072_bdvx0rs...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 103.0.5060.53, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 2d1c4aab1e9780033abcd6891537a5dsf
```

Comment: Have you tried with interactive mode and is this working? second thing you need to accept cookies before proceed to next step.

Comment: @KunduK cookies are accepted. I am not aware about interactive mode. What is it?

Comment: try without headless mode.

Comment: @KunduK same error even with open browser. I am able to fill the other text box and click the submit button, but this checkbox cannot find apparently.

Comment: Hello, There is no one can help my issue??