# WebDriverException: Message: The command 'GET /session/7.../displayed' was not found while Explicit Wait with safaridriver and Selenium 3.13.0

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver, selenium3

I am using explicit wait like below to check if element is clickable.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search")))
```

But I get error

```
 <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>
Message: The command 'GET /session/.../displayed' was not found.
```

If I use `time.sleep()` it works fine instead of explicir wait it works fine. I have initialized safari driver as

```
from selenium.webdriver import Safari
driver = Safari()
```

Here is stacktrace

```
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 283, in __call__
    element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 127, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 147, in _element_if_visible
    return element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 490, in is_displayed
    return self._execute(Command.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED)['value']
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: The command 'GET /session/7.../displayed' was not found.
```

Comment: Have you imported this `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC `

Comment: Since `time.sleep()` is extreme case of explicit wait , nothing else. this should `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search")))` work

Comment: yes it's not a import error, ideally it should work

Comment: Can you provide your confirmation?

Answer (score 5):

This error message...

```
 <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>
Message: The command 'GET /session/.../displayed' was not found.
```

...implies that the **GET** *request* to `/session/{session id}/element/{element id}/displayed` failed.

---

### element displayed

As per the [**WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) the [**element displayed**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#element-displayedness) algorithm is a *boolean* state where `true` signifies that the element is **displayed** and `false` signifies that the element is **not displayed**. To compute the state on element, invoke the `Call(bot.dom.isShown, null, element)`. If doing so does not produce an error, return the return value from this function call. Otherwise return an error with *error code* **unknown error**.

This function is typically exposed to GET requests with a URI Template of

```
/session/{session id}/element/{element id}/displayed
```

---

### Analysis

You have invoked:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search")))
```

`element_to_be_clickable()` class internally invokes `visibility_of_element_located()` and is defined as:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
    self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
    element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
    if element and element.is_enabled():
        return element
    else:
        return False
```

Now, `visibility_of_element_located()` class returns `_element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))` which is defined as:

```
class visibility_of_element_located(object):
    """ An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a
    page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed
    but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
    locator - used to find the element
    returns the WebElement once it is located and visible
    """
    def __init__(self, locator):
    self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
    try:
        return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        return False
```

Again, `_element_if_visible()` returns `element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False` which is defined as:

```
def _element_if_visible(element, visibility=True):
    return element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False
```

So, as the `if()` condition of `element.is_displayed() == visibility` **failed** hence you see the error as **`GET` request** to the **`/session/{session id}/element/{element id}/displayed`** endpoint failed.

Without the relevant *HTML* and *previous steps* it is tough to guess the exact reason but possibly can be either of the following:

---

### Reason

The reason for *NoSuchElementException* can be either of the following :

- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't identifies any element in the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted is unable to identify the element as it is not within the browser's [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted identifies the element but is invisible due to presence of the attribute **style="display: none;"**.
- The *Locator Strategy* you have adopted doesn't **uniquely** identifies the desired element in the *HTML DOM* and currently finds some other *hidden* / *invisible* element.
- The *WebElement* you are trying to locate is within an `<iframe>` tag.

---

### Solution

The solution to address *NoSuchElementException* can be either of the following :

- Adopt a [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which uniquely identifies the desired *WebElement*. You can take help of the *Developer Tools* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) and use *Element Inspector*.

  Here you will find a detailed discussion on [how to inspect element in selenium3.6 as firebug is not an option any more for FF 56?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-in-selenium3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-for-f/46702281#46702281)
- Use [**`execute_script()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method to scroll the element in to view as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
  ```

  Here you will find a detailed discussion on [Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium/45581830#45581830)
- Incase element is having the attribute **style="display: none;"**, remove the attribute  through `executeScript()` method as follows :

  ```
  elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", elem)
  elem.send_keys("text_to_send")
  ```
- To check if the element is within an `<iframe>` traverse up the *HTML* to locate the respective `<iframe>` tag and `switchTo()` the desired *iframe* through either of the following methods :

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_name")
  driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_id")
  driver.switch_to.frame(1) // 1 represents frame index
  ```

  Here you can find a detailed discussion on [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879).

Comment: Thanks for info! Apparently it's known issue "This is a known issue with safari/safaridriver and they are aware of it. Using the Safari Technology Preview should work."