# How to "scroll up" in div using selenium in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape job details in LinkedIn. As per now, I am able to scroll till the end of list.
code:

```
#scrolling till buttom of page(online job section)
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="jobs-search-results jobs-search-results--is-two-pane"]')
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', target)
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
time.sleep(1)
```

now I want to scroll up to the top of the div.
I want to scroll up in div shown as red rectangle:

[image: red rectangle showing div]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium)

[Scroll Element into View with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

There is 2 main way to do that:

Firstly, you can locate the element(at the top of your DOM view) in the DOM and then scrolling up until you find the element

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Secondly, you can easily use *CTRL+HOME* for scrolling to the top of the page with the help of *Keys*

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
```

But in your situation which dealing with JavaScript DOM, recommended way is the first one.

Comment: element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")
this code help me. but one thing is in linkedin it is dynamic when u scroll it loads data . so in order to go to top of result i have to scroll 5  time skipping 5 elements at time. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Parallel to you, DOM viewm like Google Maps or Linkedin scroll bars, it is hard to scroll up or down with selenium without core javascript code. Also usually, if you want to scrool to the bottom of the view, you should use while loop until there is no new element in the DOM view.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, here is one way:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
```

Alternatively you can scroll up with the mouse:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.scroll(10)
```

Comment: Hi this will scroll the window screen . In my case i want to scroll up in division .