# Unable to click button Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am web-scraping reviews from Goodreads for a project. Here's an example of a page I've been trying: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2767052-the-hunger-games/reviews?

The reviews page initially shows 30 reviews with a 'Show More' button at the bottom. Selenium seems unable to click the button.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
showmore_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div/button/span[1]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", showmore_button)
```

I have also tried
`showmore_button.click()`
but that leads to an exception stating that the element is not clickable

For more context my driver is set up like this:

```
def createdriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')  
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    return driver
```

and then I use:

```
driver = createdriver()
driver.get(url)
```

Where the URL is the reviews page I'm trying to scrape

Comment: Where did you get this path from and why are you clicking not on the button, but on the span element?

Comment: @СергейКох I have also tried the button but unfortunately it led to the same result. I inspected the page using Chrome's built in tools and copied the full xpath from the element

Comment: I got this path - `/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[4]/div/button`. It might be better to find the button by `class="Button Button--secondary Button--small"`

Comment: @Alex please share your code make this request request

Comment: @СергейКох I tried both but it was unable to locate element for either option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Show more reviews</kbd> at the bottom of the page you need to [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581830/7429447) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2767052-the-hunger-games/reviews?')
  time.sleep(5)
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ReviewsList__listContext ReviewsList__listContext--centered']//span[contains(., 'Displaying 1 -')]"))))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Show more reviews']"))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: Show more reviews]

Comment: Thank you! Completely solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

As the page loads for few milli-seconds before the element is displayed, you need to apply selenium waits. Try using **implicit wait** after creating the driver instance, see code below:

```
driver = createdriver()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
```

Above code waits for 10 seconds searching for the element before throwing error

**Also another suggestion:**
Instead of using an **absolute** XPath, as a best practice use **relative** XPath. This is because relative XPath is more consistent compared to absolute XPath. Absolute XPath may stop working, If the DOM structure changes in the future. Try the below relative XPath:

```
showmore_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Show more reviews")]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", showmore_button)
```