# Element could not be scrolled into view when trying to follow PayPal payment link

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, paypal, webdriverwait, js-scrollintoview

I'm using Python to try and follow a PayPal link/button but am unsure what element I need to select.

If I try to select the top level input (input id=paymentToken) with something like the following:

```
paymentToken = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'paymentToken')
paymentToken.click()
```

Then I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="paymentToken" type="hidden"> could not be scrolled into view
```

I've tried all kind of things (switch to frames etc) but I'm kind of unsure which element I *should* be trying to interact with.  Any help appreciated.

Update:

If I inspect the PayPal button, I am take to the following element:

```
<img class="paypal-button-logo paypal-button-logo-paypal paypal-button-logo-gold" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="" aria-label="paypal">
```

Please see the attached screenshot:

[image: PayPal Payment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Then you need to [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581830/7429447) the elements as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.zoid-component-frame.zoid-visible")))
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.paypal-button-label-container img.paypal-button-logo.paypal-button-logo-paypal.paypal-button-logo-gold[aria-label='paypal']")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
  element.click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately I'm still getting an unable to locate element error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: input#paymentToken
```

Comment: @crazzyfool I don't see any `<input>` in the attached [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA1Ba.jpg) but I find the highlighted `<img>`. Are you looking for that?

Comment: Yeah if I inspect the PayPal button it takes me to the <img class=paypal-button-log .....> tag.

Comment: @crazzyfool Can you paste the entire line _`<img class=paypal-button-log .....>`_ tag?

Comment: It's pretty long heheh so I've updated my post with that info.

Comment: The script ran without error but the button was not clicked. It does seem to physically scroll down the page though.

Comment: Bingo - that was it!! You are a super hero! Thanks @undetected-selenium!