# How to click on the pagination element on binance.com website with Selenium Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, click, webdriverwait, js-scrollintoview

Can't click on found element with Selenium python. I'm trying to scrape the link:

https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/futures

I have successfully scraped the first page, however, I am trying to get to page 2. For this I use the following commands, but it is not working.

```
a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="page-2"]')
a.click()
```

Oddly, when I print(`a`) it finds the element, but unfortunately I can't click it.
Print(`a`) answer:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9dbf9eafdc008e627b8b13face212b45", element="454a2787-33df-4067-b93a-8b73e259bebb")>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on *Page* ***2*** you need to [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581830/7429447) the element first then inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and `id` attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/futures")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='page-2']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='page-2']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `aria-label` attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/futures")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Page number 2']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Page number 2']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `text()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/futures")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-bn-type='button' and text()='2']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-bn-type='button' and text()='2']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: binance]

- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript's `execute_script` method to perform the `click()` action.

Change your code as below:

```
a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-2"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", a)
```

**Full working code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard/futures')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-2"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", a)
```

**Result:**

[image]