# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException error clicking on a toggle button on yahoo finance income statement data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to webscrape Income Statement data from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL

I am trying to simulate a click on Operating Expense to expand the row to see the Research and Development values like such:
[image: Research and Development rows]

This is my code so far:

```
def clickOperatingExpense(url):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        # This is where I encounter a selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/button'))).click()
```

Just for some more information, the full error is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button aria-label="Operating Expense" class="P(0) M(0) Va(m) Bd(0) Fz(s) Mend(2px) tgglBtn">...</button> is not clickable at point (39, 592). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="1" class="lightbox-wrapper Ta(c) Pos(f) T(0) Start(0) H(100%) W(100%) Bgc($modalBackground) Ovy(a) Z(50) Op(1)">...</div>
```

The issue looks like a div tag would receive the click but I'm not sure why. How can I make the  tag receive the click instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click and expand the element with text as ***Operating Expense*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[title='Operating Expense'] > button[aria-label='Operating Expense']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Close']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Operating Expense']/button[@aria-label='Operating Expense']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: OperatingExpence]

- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This solution worked. Quick question: Why does this line ```WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Close']"))).click()``` fix my issue? What is this line of code actually clicking?

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Close']"))).click()` clicks and closes the popup which obstructs the click on the desired element.

Comment: The script is able to run successfully most of the time but I sometimes encounter a similar error but on a different tag and it seems to be a threading issue: 
```Other element would receive the click: <html data-color-theme="light" id="atomic" class="chrome desktop JsEnabled themelight layoutEnhance(TwoColumnLayout) CollapsibleUh onDemandFocusSupport HideNavrail hasScrolled scrollDown" lang="en-US" style="">...</html>
```
This time the <html> tag is intercepting the click instead of a <div> tag

Comment: @AJGoudel Sounds to be a different issue. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Java script to perform click()  as below:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645682/7598774