# cannot scroll to the top from down until it reaches the top of the page using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I have a page which scrolls from the bottom (the latest feeds) to the top (the older feeds). I am trying to get Selenium to scroll all the way to the top so I can get all the information. Currently, I am using this for testing and it worked, but I have to give specific number of loops to make it work. Problem is that numbers vary so I am looking for a way where it stops when it scrolls all the way to the top.

This is working but not reusable solution.

```
number_of_loops = 1

while number_of_loops != 10:
    html = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'html')
    html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_UP)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Number of Loops:",number_of_loops)
    number_of_loops += 1
```

I tried this but it did not scroll at all. I think it was in a constant loop but again nothing happened.

```
while True:
    html = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'html')
    html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_UP)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I tried some of these solutions but nothing worked so far for me.

[How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

[Scrolling to top of the page in Python using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576958/scrolling-to-top-of-the-page-in-python-using-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JS command below to scroll to the top of the page instantly.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")
```

Comment: I tried it but this didn't work either.

Comment: Post a link to the page? If it's a lazy loading page, you may need to repeatedly scroll up.

Comment: I can't post a link due to security reasons but it seems like a lazy loading page. So there is no workaround other than repeatedly scroll up?

Comment: Correct. There is no way to scroll to the top/bottom of a lazy loading page. That's the way it's designed.